# Forwarding outgoing traffic to different port

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, nat

The application in my linux box is connecting to "ip.example.com".

The ip address for "ip.example.com" is defined in /etc/hosts as

```
10.23.22.1 ip.example.com
```

At the destination IP, a service is running on port 8080. However, the application is trying to connect `10.23.22.1:80` and it fails. There is no way to modify the destination IP or the application running in local.

I would like to forward the outgoing traffic from `10.23.11.1:80` to `10.23.22.1:8080` in my local box.

Is this possible to achieve in ip tables?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible using a rule like:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.23.11.1 -j DNAT --to-destination :8080
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is not a principle to use iptables, i would advise to use nginx (or another web server) and proxy path module:

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_connect_timeout 9999h;
  proxy_send_timeout 240;
  proxy_read_timeout 9999h;
  proxy_pass http://10.23.22.1:8080;
}
```